# How to find the most active bitcoin addresses?

Tags: blockchain, address, monitoring

Is there a way (preferably a webpage) where I can find a list of the most active bitcoin addresses, sorted by number of transactions, possibly also filtered by a timeframe?

I am not interested in the addresses with the highest balance, but with the highest number of transactions, in the last X days.

Comment: I’m not aware of a service that surfaces addresses in that manner

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Analyse huge amount of blockchain data](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/116053/13866)